# React web page can't compile after importing npm modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vs-web-site-project

I have a webpage that has a button, built with react. I want to execute some js code when the button is clicked. The code I want to execute is an npm module I made that requires 'pg' and 'fs', and will handle communications with a psql server. When I add "const database = require('../datadb/datadb.js')" (line 2) to my code, react fails to compile. Below is the code for my button.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
const database = require('../datadb/datadb.js'); //HERE is the line that causes compilation failure

/* 
A function that handles when the LoadData button is clicked. This will allow for the data to be loaded in and stored into a database that can then be referenced.
*/
function Data() {
  alert("'The data is loading'"); //Creates a pop up box
  //HERE is where I will want to execute my modules code
}

/*
This function creates a component for the buttons. 
*/
class LoadData extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={Data}>Load Data</button>
        <button>Open</button>
        <button>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default LoadData;
```

Which gives the error message:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/datadb/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js
  Line 1180:37:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 1181:3:   'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 1185:35:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 1186:3:   'semver' is not defined  no-undef
```

I have tested my `datadb` module by itself self and it has worked properly. The webpage loads properly and the button works (as in the alert works properly on line 10)

I am very new to web page related coding like react and javascript (most of my experience is in Java and some C) and was handed this project to implement my code, but I did not make the webpage or the button, so I am very unfamiliar with react. Are npm modules not exportable to react?

Here is the datadb.js file as requested

```
var fs = require('fs')
const {Client} = require('pg')






/**Connects to the client, then inserts all of the data from the given data array
 * 
 * @param {*} dataArray the data to insert
 * @param {*} client the DB client to connect to
 */
var insertRawData = async function(dataArray) {

    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        password: "password123",
        post: "5432",
        database: "first"
    })
    try {
        await client.connect()
        await client.query("BEGIN")

        var length = dataArray.length;
        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            queryString = "INSERT INTO rawdata.rawtable VALUES ( " + dataArray[i][0] + ", '" + dataArray[i][1] + "', " + dataArray[i][2] + ", " + dataArray[i][3] + ", " + dataArray[i][4] + ", " + dataArray[i][5] + ", " + dataArray[i][6] + ", " + dataArray[i][7] + ", " + dataArray[i][8] + ", " + dataArray[i][9] + ", " + dataArray[i][10] + ")" ;
            await client.query(queryString)
            console.log("NEW ROW INSERTED: " + queryString);
        }
        await client.query("COMMIT")

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("somethings wrong" + err)
    } finally {
        await client.end()
        console.log("Connection ended")
    }
}


/** 
 * Deletes all of the entries in the rawdata.rawtable table
 */
var deleteAllData = async function() {

    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        password: "password123",
        post: "5432",
        database: "first"
    })

    try {
        await client.connect()
        await client.query("DELETE FROM rawdata.rawtable WHERE year=1 OR year!=1")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("somethings wrong" + err)
    } finally {
        await client.end()
        console.log("Connection ended")
    }
}


/** 
 * Returns the entire database
 */
var getAllData = async function () {
    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        password: "password123",
        post: "5432",
        database: "first"
    })

    var data;
    try {
        await client.connect()
        data = await client.query("SELECT * FROM rawdata.rawtable")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("somethings wrong" + err)
    } finally {
        await client.end()
        console.log("Connection ended")
    }
    return data;
}

/** takes raw data returned from a SELECT psql query as input, returns the data 
 * in a 2d array format
 * 
 * @param {*} data the raw data returned from a query
 * @returns {*} the parsed data
 */
var parseDataFromQuery = async function(data){
    var returnValue = [];
    console.log("DATA: " + data.rows[0].year);

    var dataSize = data.rows.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < dataSize; i++){
        returnValue.push([data.rows[i].year, data.rows[i].month, data.rows[i].occupancy, data.rows[i].adr, data.rows[i].revpar, data.rows[i].supply, data.rows[i].demand, data.rows[i].revinue, data.rows[i].cprops, data.rows[i].crooms, data.rows[i].sparts]);
    }
    console.log(returnValue);
}



var selectTest = async function(){
    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        password: "password123",
        post: "5432",
        database: "first"
    })

    var data;
    try {
        await client.connect()
        data = await client.query("SELECT * FROM rawdata.rawtable WHERE year=9 AND month='Jan'")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("somethings wrong" + err)
    } finally {
        await client.end()
        console.log("Connection ended")
    }

    console.log(parseDataFromQuery(data, ['year']));
    //return data;
}



/**
 * Exports the functions to be used elsewhere
 */
module.exports = {
    insertRawData: insertRawData,
    deleteAllData: deleteAllData,
    getAllData: getAllData,
    selectTest: selectTest,
    parseDataFromQuery: parseDataFromQuery
};
```

Comment: Could you show us the 'datadb/datadb.js' file ?

Comment: @AntoineFrau, thanks for your comment. definitely, the issue comes from this file.

Comment: @AntoineFrau My post has been updated. I have been doing some research and am learning about Express Server. From what I understand, react is client side and my node/psql is all server side, so I will need to facilitate the communication between them, and thats what Express server can do.

Comment: Ok I see, yes you totally right, this code should run on a Express app, and then do API call from your React to this Express server.

Comment: your `datadb.js` file and also, your codes are not consistent. why you use `var`? why you import the things buy using `require`? why you export the things by using `module.exports`? I believe you should read **Ecmascript ^** declaration and its comment syntaxes. you should make a CodeSandBox and upload your re-production project with this issue three. maybe someone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

So as we figure it out, you tried to run a server side code (using PostgreSQL lib) in the react frontend app, that what causes your code to doesn't compile.

So I will suggest you to take a look at those links to understand how to create a NodeJS API server, with Express and PostgreSQL.

1. https://medium.com/@olinations/build-a-crud-template-using-react-bootstrap-express-postgres-9f84cc444438 (ReactJS + Express + PostgreSQL)
2. https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-postgresql-d96d6fc892d8/ (Only Express + PostgreSQL)
3. https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/nodejs-express-postgresql-tutorial-part-1-960 (Only Express + PostgreSQL)

And finally recommend you to take a look at [Axios](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/), which will help you to make call to your API.

Have fun !

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the resources!

Comment: Make sure to validate the answer it's always pleasant !

Answer (score -1):

A few possible solutions for this issue.

1. Please use `import` instead of `require` for your module - although it seems the same, Webpack might treat dynamic import and requirements in a different way while compiling the code.
2. Judging by the name of your file, it's something that should rather be executed on the server-side (a.k.a Node.js service), not the client-side (in this case - React Single Page Application). Perhaps try moving the logic associated with the database on the server side and compile this logic there?

Comment: Thus the "possible" keyword for both solutions.